# Can "in" mean "via"?

Tags: meaning

Consider the following sentence,

"Your request will be confirmed in an e-mail".

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If it is, could someone please explain what "in" means here?

PS - I think I've asked the question in the wrong exchange. Sorry.

Comment: _You request_ is not correct. The rest is fine.

Comment: Please tell me what "in" means here

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? You write something in a book, in an e-mail, in folder, in a document, etc. This is no different.

Comment: Think of  "Your request will be confirmed in an e-mail" as an acceptable shortening of "Your request will be confirmed; we will send you the confirmation in an e-mail". And "Your request will be confirmed via e-mail" as an acceptable (in fact, better) paraphrase of "Your request will be confirmed; you will receive this confirmation by our sending you an e-mail".

Comment: "You will find confirmation of your request with an email."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive an email, and within the email, there will be a statement of confirmation of your request.

There are multiple prepositions that could also be used. Some propositions should be used with 'email' rather than an email.'

```
Keep the 'an' 
within (rare) 
by 
via

Can omit the 'an'
by
via
```